# Java - Como capturar dados do JFormattedTextField e Validar

Tags: java, window-builder

Boa noite,

Estou com o seguinte problema.
Não sei como faço para validar se o campo do JFormatted TextField tem algo escrito ou não, com tanto que a formatação ###.###.###-## não seja considerada valida ou seja é necessário realmente está preenchida por números.

**JFormattedTextField**

```
        // CPF
    JLabel lblCpf = new JLabel("CPF");
    contentPane.add(lblCpf, "cell 0 0");

    JFormattedTextField ftCpf = new JFormattedTextField();
    MaskFormatter mfCPF = new MaskFormatter();
    try {
        mfCPF.setMask("###.###.###-##");
        mfCPF.install(ftCpf);
        ftCpf.setText("");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    contentPane.add(ftCpf, "cell 0 1,growx");
```

**Botão Ok**

```
// Botão > Ok
    JButton btnOk = new JButton("Ok");
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            // Validar Campos
            if(ftCpf.equals("###.###.###-##") && tfPergunta.getText().equals("") && tfResposta.getText().equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preenchao todos os campos acima", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else if(tfPergunta.getText().equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preenchao campo de Pergunta.", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else if(tfResposta.getText().equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor, preenchao campo da Resposta.", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Campos preenchidos.", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            // Capturar Dados
                String cpf = mfCPF.getMask();
                String pergunta = tfPergunta.getText();
                String resposta = tfResposta.getText();
        }

    });
    panel.add(btnOk, "cell 0 0,grow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Júnior

Caso o CPF possuir uma classe para representação de sí, a validação pode ser feita dentro de sua própria classe, tenha um método para verificação se o valor recebido pelo TextField é nulo ou vazio, atravez de uma String.

Outros tipos de validações podem ser feitas com os próprios métodos da classe String, e junto a String cpf pode também valídar fazendo uso de RegEx.

Por exemplo fazendo aceitando apenas letras `[a-zA-Z]*` ou apenas números `[0-9]*` ou apenas letra e numeros `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Ex:

```
public class CPF {

    private String valor;

    public CPF(String cpf) {
        if(cpf == null || cpf.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Não aceita campo vazio");
        }
        this.valor = cpf; //Caso não estiver nulo ou vazio, ele atribui o valor para o atributo da classe
    }

    public String getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Outras verificações/validações podem ser feitas dentro do construtor ou em qualquer outro método.